# Overriding values on dimens no longer working on AndroidX?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, androidx, material-components-android

I have been overriding the space between my menu icons and menu text for sometime now but, when I migrated to **androidx** the override seems to be no longer working. Any idea on how to override them on androidx?

Here is my current override on `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen tools:override="true"name="design_navigation_icon_padding">10dp</dimen>
<dimen tools:override="true"name="design_navigation_icon_margin">5dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the [attributes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/navigation/res/values/dimens.xml) used in the new [`NavigationView`](https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/) in the Material Components for Android library.

```
  <dimen name="design_navigation_max_width">280dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="design_navigation_elevation">16dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="design_navigation_item_icon_padding">32dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="design_navigation_item_horizontal_padding">16dp</dimen>

  <dimen name="mtrl_navigation_elevation">0dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="mtrl_navigation_item_icon_padding">14dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="mtrl_navigation_item_icon_size">24dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="mtrl_navigation_item_horizontal_padding">22dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="mtrl_navigation_item_shape_horizontal_margin">8dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="mtrl_navigation_item_shape_vertical_margin">4dp</dimen>
```

However the best way to change these values is to use the [xml attributes](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationView.html#attr_NavigationView_itemIconPadding)  like `itemIconPadding` in the layout.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
  ...
  app:itemIconPadding="@dimen/myvalue"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use new material **NavigationView** with `app:itemIconPadding`:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                        ...
                        app:itemIconPadding="@dimen/navigation_icon_padding"/>
```

**dimens.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="navigation_icon_padding">12dp</dimen>
</resources>
```